# Does the normal of any plane pass through every single point in space? If so, why?

Tags: vector-spaces, plane-geometry

The normal is a direction vector that is perpendicular to (edited) the plane at all points. Is the normal then able to pass through every single point in space?

Edit: Suppose I can shift the normal around at all points on the plane, am I able to form a line equation of the normal passing through every single point in space?

Comment: The subspace spanned by a vector is one-dimensional. So unless your vector space is also one-dimensional, the answer is no.

Comment: A vector can't be perpendicular to a point. So what you say makes no sense.

Comment: Yes. Just look at it the other way - from each point in space you can find the line perpendicular to the plane.